# Selecting some elements in python lists

Tags: python, list, sequence

I have this list:

```
[[10:09:56.033,ComponentB,2,DEBUG,description],
[10:09:56.034,ComponentB,1,DEBUG,description],
[10:09:57.034,ComponentB,2,DEBUG,description],
[10:09:57.045,ComponentB,2,DEBUG,description]]
```

How can I print all timestamps. like:

```
10:09:56.033
10:09:56.034
10:09:57.034
10:09:57.045
```

Also how can I print only timestamps per some second, like:

```
10:09:56.033
10:09:56.034
```

Comment: First of all I would fix it, because that list is invalid.

Comment: Please post some code of what you have tried and does not work. If we know what you are trying, we can help.

Comment: @sid16rgt I`m trying this code:

    row_taker = [row.split() for row in log_file]
    print(row_taker[0][0])

But obviously it will print only one item.

    for line in row_taker:
        print row_taker[0]

Will be correct to make something like this:

    for line in row_taker:
        for prv, nxt in zip(row_taker,row_taker[1:]):
            if i < max:
                print element, row_taker[i]

Comment: @sid16rgt sorry, I cant edit my msg, cause lack of reputation here...

Comment: @smith you can always edit your own question (and anyone elses butthese will mean the edit is reviewed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` and `datetime.strptime`:

```
from itertools import groupby
from datetime import datetime
def solve(item):
    dt = datetime.strptime(item[0], '%H:%M:%S.%f')
    return dt.hour, dt.minute, dt.second

lis = [['10:09:56.033', 'ComponentB', 2, 'DEBUG', 'description'], ['10:09:56.034', 'ComponentB', 1, 'DEBUG', 'description'], ['10:09:57.034', 'ComponentB', 2, 'DEBUG', 'description'], ['10:09:57.045', 'ComponentB', 2, 'DEBUG', 'description']]

for k, g in groupby(lis, key=solve):
    print '\n'.join(x[0] for x in g) + '\n'
```

**Output:**

```
10:09:56.033
10:09:56.034

10:09:57.034
10:09:57.045
```

---

Other alternative to `datetime` object coversion is to use `str.partition('.')`([Suggested](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/12622663#12622663) by @jonclements: ):

```
for k, g in groupby(lis, key=lambda x:x[0].partition('.')[0]):
    print '\n'.join(x[0] for x in g) + '\n'
```

Comment: Good answer, better than mine atleast.

Comment: I just used your answer, but used lambdas instead! :P

Comment: @GamesBrainiac Hi! Is Lambda more powerful ? size of log file is 10GB

Comment: @smith "powerful" is a _very_ abstract term. However, my lambda is much shorter than his _solve_ so, it _should_ be faster.

Comment: @hcwhsa one more question : I have now grouped column by time, how can i make such calculations: time : [11:10:02] ComponentA - 888 appearings, so I need to calculate how many time per second ComponentA appered, thank You

Comment: @smith For that you need to create a list first and then use `collections.Counter`: `lis = list(g);c = Counter(x[1] for x in lis);`

Answer (score 1):

Printing all the stamps:

```
stamps = [
    ['10:09:56.033', 'ComponentB', 2, 'DEBUG', 'description'],
    ['10:09:56.034', 'ComponentB', 1, 'DEBUG,description'],
    ['10:09:57.034', 'ComponentB', 2, 'DEBUG,description'],
    ['10:09:57.045', 'ComponentB', 2, 'DEBUG,description']
]

for var in stamps:
    print var[0]
```

As for printing for each second(a variation of hcwhsa's answer, using lambdas instead of a separate function all together):

```
from itertools import groupby


lis = [['10:09:56.033', 'ComponentB', 2, 'DEBUG', 'description'],
       ['10:09:56.034', 'ComponentB', 1, 'DEBUG', 'description'],
       ['10:09:57.034', 'ComponentB', 2, 'DEBUG', 'description'],
       ['10:09:57.045', 'ComponentB', 2, 'DEBUG', 'description']]

for k, g in groupby(lis, key=lambda item: item[0][0:8]):
    print k
    print '\n'.join(x[0] for x in g) + '\n'
```

This *should* be faster.

Comment: one more question : I have now grouped column by time, how can i make such calculations: time : [11:10:02] ComponentA - 888 appearings, so I need to calculate how many time per second ComponentA appered, thank You

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `my_list` is your list, and the first element is a string

1.

```
for item in my_list:
    print item[0]
```

2.

```
for item in my_list:
    if item[0].startswith('10:09:56.'):
        print item[0]
```